# Get hidden field text to appear in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I encountered a problem. I wish to get a hidden field text to appear in a textbox when I click on a button so I can show the user what the input is. It is necessary for me to use a hidden field, as I'm getting the hidden field value via javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a "runat" server property to the hidden field, you can access that in your code behind.

```
<asp:TextBox id="desiredTextBox" runat="server />
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnVal" value=""  />
```

codebehind of button click event

```
desiredTextBox.Text=hdnVal.value;
```

If you want to do it in the client side, you can use jQuery to get and set the value

```
  $("#yourButtonId").click(function(){
     $("#desiredTextBox").val($("#hdnVal").val());
  });
```

Comment: This isn't why he wants. see his comments under my answer. His question could have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the value of hidden input is exactly the same like "unhidden" input:

**Pure javascript:**

```
var value = document.getElementById('theId').value;
alert(value);
```

**jQuery:**

```
var value = $('#theId').val();
alert(value);
```

**Full Demo of jquery click event:**

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
        alert($('#theId').val());
    });
```

Comment: i did try the .value method. and i am able to get something into the hidden field. but i wish to display the hidden field text

Comment: @lixi. What do you mean "display"? it's value with alert, or show the hidden itself?

Comment: @lixi. Do it with alert, I added it to my answer.